# jQuery ("checked", true) works, then doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Please see this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7Rbr/)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <button type="button" class="form-clear">Clear</button>
  <button type="button" class="form-set">Set</button>
  <input type="text" value="Preset value" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".form-clear").click(function(){
  $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('');
  $(':checkbox, :radio').attr('checked', false);
});
$(".form-set").click(function(){
  $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('New preset value');
  $(':checkbox, :radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

1. Click **Set** first. This will input "New preset value" and check the second checkbox.
2. Click **Clear** to clear the whole form.
3. Click **Set** again. This will input "New preset value" **but will not** check the second checkbox.

I'm guessing there's a conflict between the two functions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The *attribute* actually corresponds to the *defaultChecked property* and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox.

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$(".form-clear").click(function(){
    $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('');
    $(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', false);
});
$(".form-set").click(function(){
    $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('New preset value');
    $(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checked property

```
$(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', true);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2LeQZ/)

[Attributes vs. Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Comment: It's worth to mention that checked is a boolean prop.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

`$(':checkbox, :radio').prop('checked', true);`