# Going crazy with jQuery and multiple checkbox set

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Just discovered a crazy thing using jQuery and I just can't explain it.
In the return of a $.getJSON, I've to unset/set some checkbox regarding to which categories are returned by the JSON.
Before calling the JSON, I did :

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name^='category_']").each(function() { this.checked = false; });
```

Which works perfectly.
Then, inside the result function of the getJSON, I did this:

```
var checkedCats = data.categories.split(';');
for (i=0; i<checkedCats.length; i++) {
    $('#category_'+checkedCats[i]).attr('checked',true);
}
```

And that works... randomly... Sometimes checking boxes, sometimes not...
The craziest thing is that, when I transform this code to:

```
var checkedCats = data.categories.split(';');
for (i=0; i<checkedCats.length; i++) {
    var aCheckbox = document.getElementById('category_'+checkedCats[i]);
    aCheckbox.checked = true;
}
```

Then this code works perfectly...

Is there any reason ?

Comment: You ought to use `.prop('checked',true)` instead of `attr`

Comment: And did you try using the proper method `prop('checked', true)` ?

Comment: You need to use prop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435346/jquery-checked-true-works-then-doesnt-work